# Completing tasks in a certain order using android's JobScheduler

Tags: java, android, jobs, android-jobscheduler

I have job A and job B. They are both network related. I need the jobs to be completed in  this order: ABA whenever the network is available, but instead, job scheduler completes the jobs in this order: AAB. How can i run tasks when network is available in certain order? Is it possible with JobScheduler? If not, what should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i run tasks when network is available in certain order?

Combine them into one job that does ABA (or AB, if ABAB and ABABAB are fine).

> Is it possible with JobScheduler?

Not as two separate jobs.

> If not, what should I use to achieve this?

Use a single job. Or, use a single alarm with `AlarmManager`. Or use one-off alarms with `AlarmManager`, where you initially set up a one-off alarm for A, and it sets up a one-off alarm for B as part of its work (B, in turn, sets up a one-off alarm for A as part of *its* work).

A and B should not be separate things. IMHO, A and B are useless in isolation, if ABA is valid and AAB is not.